# How to stop a csv file overwriting

Tags: python, csv

this code asks a user to input a barcode, my program then opens a csv file and accesses a database , there are 4 different products, the user eneters how many of the product they want and then asks if they want to keep shopping or press 0 and stop shopping and print a receipt (which is another csv file) , my problem is that my program does not take previous orders into account and only the last one , if that makes sense (if i order 3 tomatoes and then 4 pieces of celery it only takes the amount of celery into account). I want to apoligise for poor english as it is not my primary language. Here is the part of the code which i think is going wrong

```
def quantity():
    fileOne = open('receipt.csv', 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(fileOne)
    global total_price
    product_data = read_csv_file()
    matches = search_user_input(product_data)
    if matches: # Will not be True if search_user_input returned None
        print("apple")
        product, price = matches[0], matches[1]
        order = int(input("How much of {} do you want?".format(product)))
        values = [str(product), str(price), str(order*price)]
        writer.writerows((values,))
        total_price.append(order * price)
    continue_shopping=int(input("press 0 to stop shopping and print your reciept or press 1 to continue shopping"))
    if (continue_shopping == 0):
        fileOne.close()
        fileTwo = open("receipt.csv" , "r")
        reader = csv.reader(fileTwo)
        for row in reader:
            if row != None:
                print(row)
    elif continue_shopping==1:
        quantity()

quantity()
```

Here is the rest of the code if you are curious.

```
import csv 
import locale

total_price = []

locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, '' )
def read_csv_file():
    global total_price
    """ reads csv data and appends each row to list """
    csv_data = []
    with open("task2.csv") as csvfile:
         spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar="|")
         for row in spamreader:
             csv_data.append(row)
    return csv_data


def get_user_input():
    global total_price
    """ get input from user """
    while True:
        try:
            GTIN = int(input("input your gtin-8 number: "))
            return GTIN # Breaks the loop and returns the value
        except:
            print ("Oops! That was not a valid number.  Try again")


def search_user_input(product_data):
    global total_price
    repeat=""
    # Pass the csv data as an argument
    """ search csv data for string """
    keep_searching = True

    while keep_searching:
        gtin = get_user_input()
        for row in product_data:
            if row[0] == str(gtin):
                product = row[1]
                price = round(float(row[2]),2)
                return(product, price)
        while True:
            try:
                repeat = input("not in there? search again? If so (y), else press enter to continue")
                break
            except:
                print("please make sure you enter a valid string") 
        if repeat != 'y':
            keep_searching = False 
            return None 


def quantity():
    fileOne = open('receipt.csv', 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(fileOne)
    global total_price
    product_data = read_csv_file()
    matches = search_user_input(product_data)
    if matches: # Will not be True if search_user_input returned None
        print("apple")
        product, price = matches[0], matches[1]
        order = int(input("How much of {} do you want?".format(product)))
        values = [str(product), str(price), str(order*price)]
        writer.writerows((values,))
        total_price.append(order * price)
    continue_shopping=int(input("press 0 to stop shopping and print your reciept or press 1 to continue shopping"))
    if (continue_shopping == 0):
        fileOne.close()
        fileTwo = open("receipt.csv" , "r")
        reader = csv.reader(fileTwo)
        for row in reader:
            if row != None:
                print(row)
    elif continue_shopping==1:
        quantity()

quantity()
```

I appreciate any help or advice or if you do not understand a part of my code i can try to explain

Comment: `fileOne = open('receipt.csv', 'w')`: overwrites the file each time. Use append mode instead...

Comment: Append file open(csv_file, 'a')?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre So iw would use fileOne = append("reciet.csv")

Comment: @dankjellybeans - open(csv_file, 'a') is the way for append mode

Comment: Ah alright , however this does not fix my problem , the issue of the code ignoring the first product does not get taken into account